# How to regexp match groups at end of variable length comma separated string

Tags: python, regex

I have a need to get the last two elements of a comma separated string of any number of elements, that also starts with a specified value.

Here is an example of how I expect it to work.

```
def process(pattern, string):
  part1, part2 = None, None
  match = re.search(pattern, string)
  if match:
    part1 = match.group(1)
    part2 = match.group(2)
return part1, part2

regex_search = ?
string1 = must,have,blah,blah,blah,blah,grab,this
string2 = must,have,grab,that
string3 = wrong,have,drop,this

print(process(regex_search, string1)
print(process(regex_search, string2)
print(process(regex_search, string3)
```

result is supposed to be

```
('grab', 'this')
('grab', 'that')
(None, None)
```

My regexp and what its currently getting

```
regex_search = '^must,have,(.*)\\,(.*)$'

('blah,blah,blah,blah,grab', 'this')
('grab', 'that')
(None, None)
```

Edit: Thanks Wiktor!! Solution below.

```
^must,have,(?:.*,)?(.*),(.*)$
```

Comment: Maybe `^must,have,(?:.*,)?(.*),(.*)$`? Or `^must,have,(?:.*,)?([^,]*),([^,]*)$`

Comment: And a CSV parser is unsuitable why exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
,([^,]*),([^,]*$)
```

It should return only two last groups separated by commas

Answer (score 1):

instead of regex we can also use a for loop to grap the required data.

```
lst = ['must,have,blah,blah,blah,blah,grab,this','must,have,grab,that','wrong,have,drop,this']
for item in lst:
    if item.startswith('must'):
        res = item.split(',')[-2:]
        print(res)
```

result:

```
['grab', 'this']
['grab', 'that']
```